# Oozie Workflow using Maven

Tags: maven, oozie, maven-assembly-plugin, biginsights

I am trying to create an oozie application using IBM BigInsights. I believe to run the application on IBM BigInsights, the minimum folder structure should be:

```
BiApp
—> application
    —> application.xml
—> workflow
    —> lib
        —> jar files/scripts
    —> workflow.xml
```

I currently have the application set up using the default configuration provided by Maven. i.e My source code is in src/main/java/com/example/example.java

Is there a way that I can package the application in the folder structure required by IBM BigInsights?

Comment: What difficulties you have using maven assembly plugin?

Comment: @MikhailGolubtsov Could you tell me how can I achieve the folder structure using the Maven Assembly Plugin?

Comment: Did you read the plugin documentation? Have you tried actually do something? What difficulties with the plugin you have? You question looks like you spent no effort, but want a free lunch.